# Dark Mode text changes but style isn't changing Nextjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm new to Next.js but I believe it's not Next.js issue.

I seem to make the button work for Navbar but couldn't figure out the way to change whole page.

The button is placed on Navbar component.

Deployed version of the page:
[Web Page](https://project-cyber-6vb3.vercel.app/)

Github repo: https://github.com/glaucc/project-cyber

I have ThemeContext.js file:

```
// ThemeContext.js

// ThemeContext.js
// 'use client';

import React, { createContext, useState, useContext } from "react";

const ThemeContext = createContext('light');

export const lightTheme = {
  backgroundColor: "#fff",
  textColor: "#333",
  linkHoverColor: "#555",
};

export const darkTheme = {
  backgroundColor: "#222",
  textColor: "#fff",
  linkHoverColor: "#ddd",
};

const ThemeProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isDarkMode, setIsDarkMode] = useState(false);

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setIsDarkMode((prevMode) => !prevMode);
  };
  console.log(1)
  const theme = isDarkMode ? darkTheme : lightTheme;

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, toggleDarkMode }}>
      {children}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

const useTheme = () => {
  const context = useContext(ThemeContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error("useTheme must be used within a ThemeProvider");
  }
  return context;
};

export { ThemeProvider, useTheme };
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import Link from "next/link";
import styled from "styled-components";
import {useTheme, lightTheme, darkTheme}  from "../components/ThemeContext";

import '../styles/navbar.css';

// Styled component for the logo image
const LogoImage = styled.img`
margin-right: 10px; /* Add some spacing between the logo and the "Home" button */
// height: 40px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
`;

const Navbar = () => {

  const { theme, toggleDarkMode } = useTheme();
  // console.log(theme)

  const handleDarkModeToggle = () => {
    console.log("it's working");
    toggleDarkMode();
    console.log(theme)


  };

  return (
    <div className="navbar-container" style={theme}>
      {/* Logo */}
      <Link href="/">
        <a>
          <LogoImage src="/path-to-your-logo-image.png" alt="Logo" />
        </a>
      </Link>

      {/* Home Button */}
      <Link href="/">
        <div className="homebtn nav-item">Home</div>
      </Link>

      {/* Rest of the navigation items */}
      <div className="nav-items">
        <Link href="/learn">
          <div className="nav-item navitemss">Learn</div>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/practice">
          <div className="nav-item navitemss">Practice</div>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/paths">
          <div className="nav-item navitemss">Paths</div>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/login">
          <div className="nav-item navitemss">Login</div>
        </Link>
        <Link href="/signup">
          <div className="nav-item navitemss">Sign Up</div>
        </Link>
        <div className="nav-item navitemss" onClick={handleDarkModeToggle}>
          {theme === lightTheme ? "Light Mode" : "Dark Mode"}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Layout.js

```
'use client'

import styled, { keyframes } from "styled-components";
import React from "react";
import { createGlobalStyle } from "styled-components";
import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';


import { ThemeProvider, useTheme, darkTheme } from "../components/ThemeContext";


// Create a GlobalStyle component to apply the Inter font globally
const GlobalStyle = createGlobalStyle`
  @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600&display=swap');

  /* Other global styles or CSS resets can go here */

  /* Apply the Inter font to the body element */
  
  body {
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
  
  }

  a {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.textColor};
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: ${(props) => props.theme.linkHoverColor};
  }

  `;
  // background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.backgroundColor};
  // color: ${(props) => props.theme.textColor};

  
const ContentContainer = styled.div`
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
`;

// const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })
// className={inter.className}

const RootLayout = ({ children }) => {
  console.log(2)

  const { theme } = useTheme();
  console.log(3)

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ThemeProvider style={theme}>
          <GlobalStyle />
          <Navbar />
          <ContentContainer>
            {children}
          </ContentContainer>
          <Footer />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
};


export default RootLayout;
```

Console.log on 42nd line of Navbar returns this: {backgroundColor: '#222', textColor: '#fff', linkHoverColor: '#ddd'}

I've tried to find an answer with ChatGPT but t still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: I see you are changing the theme but where are you applying the theme? Because obviously the toggle is working but, have you used the theme object & if so, where? can you share that code.

Comment: İ added the code sir. here's the link for you too https://github.com/glaucc/project-cyber

Answer (score 0):

You are defining light and dark theme objects but you are not using the theme anywhere.

You need to apply your theme. For example

```
return (
    <div className="navbar-container" style={theme}>
...
)
```

Comment: This solved the navbar problem. However, I still couldn't figure out the way make iit work for for full page. 've fixed the code. Please review the github link at the start